# How to fit an Autoregression model in Spark?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, spark-mllib

I'm having a look at the implementation of Autoregression model in Scala https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkts/models/Autoregression.scala

Now if I understand correctly, one should be able to fit data containing more than one variable, for example

```
variable1 variable2 variable3
1.2       1.3       .3
.2        1.1       .5
.3        .4        .5
1.1       3.4       1.1
```

Now if I define `val variable1=Vectors.dense(1.2,.2,.3,1.1)` and run `Autoregression.fitModel(variable1,maxLag=2,noIntercept=false)` then I am able to fit the model but this is not what I want. Instead, I want to fit all the variables at the same time. 
My question is: how should I define my data in Scala in such a way that I fit all the variables into the Autoregressive model and not just one variable?

Comment: Didn't examine it very closely, but it now appears that multivariate autoregression is supported in spark (also found other related links):  https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkts/models/AutoregressionX.scala

Comment: The implemention in the link (AutoregressionX) is just Univariate Autoregression with exogenous variables (which can be a matrix indeed). Actually it's Sandy Ryza himself who claims that there is no Multivariate Vector Autoregression. Check out, however, my attempt to implement multivariate autoregression in Spark: https://github.com/antonioACR1/vector-autoregression-in-Spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, apparently there is no implementation for Multivariate Vector Autoregression in Scala according to Sandy Ryza https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spark-ts/3fNLfc6Z-cg and the current implementation is just for univariate series.

EDIT: I tried to implement myself multivariate Vector Autoregression in Spark. Check it out here https://github.com/antonioACR1/vector-autoregression-in-Spark

Notice, however, that this attempt still has some limitations. I hope to provide a full implementation soon